I want to solve the orthogonal procrustses problem, but I am confused by the deformed form.
I'm studying about orthogonal Procrustses problem.
Now, I wonder if there is a way to solve the orthogonal procrustses problem when the orthogonal matrix $Q$ is located in two or more terms. Also, the orthogonal matrix $Q$ must be in the subtraction term, but I wonder if it can be solved even if it exists in the addition term.
I'm trying to solve this problem.
I'm finding the matrix $Q$ which minimizes objective function.
Objective function is as follows, composed of the Frobenius norm. 

$||A-QB||^2_F+||Q+C-DE||^2_F$

When the objective function is structured as above, is there a way to solve the orthogonal procrustses problem?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

@JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for the advice. I changed the title and content of the question based on your advice.

Can't $C-DE$ be  treated a a single matrix? Why the superfluous variables?

Let $\,F=(DE-C)\,$ and consider two objective functions
and their corresponding gradients
$$\eqalign{
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\h{\tfrac12}
\def\w{\widehat}
\def\A{\w A}
\def\B{\w B}
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\q{\quad}
\def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\h\l\|Q-F\|^2+\h\|QB-A\|^2 &\qiq Q\LR{BB^T+\l I} &-\; \LR{AB^T+\l F} \\
\h\|Q\B-\A\|^2 &\qiq Q\;\B\B^T &-\;\; \A\B^T \\
}$$
We can make the second gradient identical to the first by setting $\B$ equal to the Cholesky factor of the SPD matrix $\LR{BB^T+\l I},\,$ then solve for an $\A$ matrix which handles the remainder
$$\eqalign{
\A\B^T &= \LR{AB^T+\l F} \qiq
\A &= \LR{AB^T+\l F}\B^{\,-T} \\
}$$
Now apply the standard Procrustes solution to the second objective function
to find $Q$.
